# Button doesn't call alert()

Tags: jquery, html

When I click the message button, it won't call alert() ..can anybody check the code please?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery.dmDropDownMenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/watermark.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylez.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" /> $(document).ready( function(){ $('#buttons button').click(function(){ switch( $('buttons').id){ case "mail": alert(1); break; } }); }); </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table width="1000" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="columnA">    
                <div id="buttons">
                    <button id="mail" class="menubutton">Message</button><br/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check which button has been clicked and you are going to have multiple buttons, you can use `$(this)` inside the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), it will reference **THE** object which was clicked. So change the switch to:

```
switch($(this).attr('id')) {
```

The full lot:

```
$('#buttons button').click(function(){
    switch( $(this).attr('id') ){
        case "mail":
            alert(1);
        break;
    }
});
```

See a working [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/ytfkN/)

Answer (score 2):

change

```
$('buttons').id
```

to:

```
$('buttons').get(0).id
```

Comment: Or just `$('buttons')[0].id`.